# How to use an if statment to respond to several different string options

Tags: python

I'm making a pizzeria experience in python and I'm having some trouble because I'm wondering how to add several string options to an if statement.

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
menu = ("    Happy Ham's Pizza Hut \n\nSIZES \nLarge pizza (20in.) \nMedium pizza (15in.) \nSmall pizza (personel 10in.)\n")
menu += ("\nTYPES \nVegan pizza(non-dairy cheese, tofu pepporoni)\nVegatarian pizza(ground-corn crust, graded radish cheese alternative, cucumber rounds)")
name = str(input(" \n Hello, and welcome to happy ham's pizza hut! \nWould you like a menu? \n >>"))
if name == ('yes, yes please'):
    print(menu)
```

Now the problem is when making the if statement I want it to have the same response for several different answers. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a case for if the user inputs `no` as an input ? and pls see into how to have good naming variables and it should be `name = str(input('ask user the question to see menu or not'))`

Comment: What I mean is like in the code above I want it to respond with printing the menu if the user says yes or yes please.

Comment: `if name in ('yes', 'yes please'):...`

Comment: yes! Finally thank you @HenryYik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the entire fixed code

```
menu = ("Happy Ham's Pizza Hut \n\nSIZES \nLarge pizza (20in.) \nMedium pizza 
       (15in.) \nSmall pizza (personel 10in.)\n")
menu += ("\nTYPES \nVegan pizza(non-dairy cheese, tofu pepporoni)\nVegatarian 
        pizza(ground-corn crust, graded radish cheese alternative, cucumber 
        rounds)")
name = str(input(" \n Hello, and welcome to happy ham's pizza hut! \nWould you 
       like a menu? \n >>"))

if name in ('yes', 'yes please'):
   print(menu)
else:
   print("Customer doesn't want to see menu")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of changes, everything looks good.

```
menu = ("Happy Ham's Pizza Hut \n\nSIZES \nLarge pizza (20in.) \nMedium pizza 
       (15in.) \nSmall pizza (personel 10in.)\n")
menu += ("\nTYPES \nVegan pizza(non-dairy cheese, tofu pepporoni)\nVegatarian 
        pizza(ground-corn crust, graded radish cheese alternative, cucumber 
        rounds)")
name = str(input(" \n Hello, and welcome to happy ham's pizza hut! \nWould you 
       like a menu? \n >>"))

acceptableresponses = ["yes", "yes please", "YES!"]
### create a list of acceptable responses to display the menu.

if name in acceptableresponses:
   print(menu)
else:
   print("Customer doesn't want to see menu")

### else case doesn't show menu rather prints a msg saying user doesn't want to see the menu since user input something other than what's in the list declared.
```

Comment: no that is not what I want, look at my comment above.

Comment: This prints the menu if user inputs `yes, yes please`.

Comment: I just ran the code in Idle, If I enter yes please it says customer doesn't want to see a menu.

Comment: why `yes please` the string is meant to only return a menu if it's `yes, yes please`? in that case it wouldn't